# scp failure: Unauthorized access is prohibited

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I try to write a script to "scp" a file from local server A to remote server B. 
What I have done is generate the public key from server A, and add it into server B "authorized_keys". Everything is find.
I do a small test, and ssh from A to B without password successfully. Here is the command

```
$ ssh userid@serverB
```

But here is the question. when I try to execute scp command, get failure because of "Unauthorized access is prohibited".

```
-bash-4.1$ scp file_name userid@serverB:~
Unauthorized access is prohibited
file_name                                         100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
```

I have spent a lots of time to find out the reason, but cannot get the right answer.
Could anyone let me know, why this happen? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't need that trailing `~`. `scp` copies to the remote user's home directory by default if you don't give a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that looks like a message that's coming out of a login script. is the file actually getting copied? I think that message has nothing to do with the success of the file copy itself.

Comment: Thanks, dldnh. What a foolish mistake I made. My head stop running in the past hours, and mislead by "Unauthorized access is prohibited". Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was a MOTD.

Wich distribution do you use ?